# Why dynamic SQL does not work

Tags: c#, sql

Why dynamic SQL does not work ??

code in C# :

```
 this.DataAccess.AddParametr("@where","WHERE ta.IdMoinRef in(112,113,115)");
```

code in sqlServer:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_tblAsnad_SelectAllForReport]
@where nvarchar(max)
As
Begin                                       
Select
        ta.IdMoinRef,
        ta.IdTafzeliRef,
        ta.ShHesab,
        ta.Bd,
        ta.Bs,
        ta.ShSnd,
        ta.AtfSnd,
        ta.DateSnd,
        mo.Hmoin,
        co.Hcol,
        gr.Hgroup,
        co.IdGroupRef,
        mo.IdColRef
    From tblAsnad as ta
    inner join tblMoin as mo on ta.IdMoinRef=mo.IdMoin
    inner join tblCol as co on mo.IdColRef=co.IdCol
    inner join tblGroup as gr on co.IdGroupRef=gr.IdGroup
    exec(@where)
End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confused.  You need to encapsulate your entire statement into a command.  You're attempting to execute one query and then an additional query.  You need to parse your main query together with your parameter, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = "SELECT ... " + @where -- Your full query.
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: @jackStone Exactly as stated above, omitting the ... for your real SELECT query.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to execute only the where-clause. For dynamic SQL statements, you must build the entire statement as a string:

```
           @s = "select * from T " + @where_clause
           exec(@s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to EXEC the whole query as one string, not just the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -1):

your code is passing the WHERE string in as a string parameter. So what your proc will execute as will be:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_tblAsnad_SelectAllForReport]
@where nvarchar(max)
As
Begin                                       
Select
        ta.IdMoinRef,
        ta.IdTafzeliRef,
        ta.ShHesab,
        ta.Bd,
        ta.Bs,
        ta.ShSnd,
        ta.AtfSnd,
        ta.DateSnd,
        mo.Hmoin,
        co.Hcol,
        gr.Hgroup,
        co.IdGroupRef,
        mo.IdColRef
    From tblAsnad as ta
    inner join tblMoin as mo on ta.IdMoinRef=mo.IdMoin
    inner join tblCol as co on mo.IdColRef=co.IdCol
    inner join tblGroup as gr on co.IdGroupRef=gr.IdGroup
    exec('WHERE ta.IdMoinRef in(112,113,115)')
End
```

Which, is obviously wrong. Your entire command needs to be in the command text here.

Comment: I was merely pointing out how the code AS IS will execute at the DBMS and therefore why it isnt working. Which was the question.